# How to find border of object represent in matrix ( coordinate system)

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have in matrix the footprint of an object, which is in short which cells the object does occupy (object are of one part, cells marked as 0 are unoccupied and cells marked as 1 are  occupied by the object). Then, I have a list of occupied cells in `list<pair<int, int> >` with matrix coordinates.

How to find all border cells of that object which belongs to that object ? (adjacent cells are for example `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2) if abs(x1-x2)<=1  && abs(y1-y2)<=1`).

```
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  1  1  0 
0  1  1  1  0 
0  1  1  1  0
0  0  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 6):

Set a pixel to 0 if all of it's neighbor pixels are 1. The remaining 1s are on a boundary:

```
for (x = 1; x < width-1; ++x) {
  for (y = 1; y < height-1; ++y) {
    if (data(x+1,y) && data(x-1,y) && data(x,y+1) && data(x,y-1)) {
      data(x,y) = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. First, find the object. It can be done using a [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).
2. All the cells found in (1) are candidates, iterate through all candidates and yield the cells which have one or more adjacent cell with value=0. (or if its in the edge of the matrix)

---

A possible optimization would be to "explore" only cells which have an adjacent cell with 0/edge of matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Use edge walking: define a window of 2x2 cells and start somewhere
outside the object, e.g. in the top left corner.  Then, move the
window around according to the pattern seen inside the window:

```
0 0
0 0
```

-> You still have to find the edge of the object.  Move two steps to
   the right; if that hits the right edge, move two steps down and all
   the way to the left (a kind of row scanning).

```
0 0
0 1
```

-> Move one step to the right.

```
0 0
1 1
```

-> Move one step to the right.

```
0 0
1 0
```

-> Move one step down.

```
0 1
0 1
```

-> Move one step up.

```
0 1
1 1
```

-> Move one step up.

etc.

You move clockwise around the edge this way.  Any 1 you encounter can
be seen as an edge part of the object; although you could treat the
lower right 1 in the last example above as not an edge (that is a
matter of definition).

You are done as soon as you encounter the position where you first hit
the edge.

Pay attention to the following corner case, which might need special
treatment (e.g. remembering having encountered it):

```
0 1
1 0
```