# Why is declaring a computationally expensive class property faster when declared in the constructor?

Tags: javascript, performance, class, optimization, accessor

I am trying to find the most efficient way to execute a certain operation.  I have a `Cell` class which represents an x, y position on a matrix.  A `Cell` needs to be able to spawn neighbor cells, like this:

```js
class Cell {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.count = 0;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    get neighbors() {
        if (this._neighbors) return this._neighbors;

        this.count++;

        const { x, y } = this;

        let neighbors = [];
        for (let j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
            for (let i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
                if (!(i === 0 && j === 0)) {
                    neighbors.push(new Cell(x + i, y + j));
                }
            }
        }
        this._neighbors = neighbors;
        return this._neighbors;
    }
}
```

You can see that for a given `new Cell`, the first time `cell.neighbors` is accessed, it generates the neighbors, and assigns them to `cell._neighbors`.  Every subsequent access of `cell.neighbors` simply returns the value that was already computed.

I compared this against a method wherein the neighbors are not an accessor method, but rather simply created as part of the class instance in the constructor:

```js
class Cell {
    constructor(x, y, makeNeighbors = true) {
        this.count = 0;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        if (makeNeighbors) {
            this.neighbors = this.getNeighbors();
        }
    }

    getNeighbors() {
        this.count++;

        const { x, y } = this;

        let neighbors = [];
        for (let j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
            for (let i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
                if (!(i === 0 && j === 0)) {
                    neighbors.push(new Cell(x + i, y + j, false));
                }
            }
        }
        return neighbors;
    }
}
```

In this case, creating a `new Cell(x, y)` will have the neighbors calculated when the instance is created.  The `makeNeighbors` boolean is to make sure that every subsequent created `Cell` doesn't try to calculate *its* neighbors and put us in an inifite loop.  This is working well.

I compared these two methods with jsbench.me, with the following code:

```
const cells = Array.from({ length: 100 }).map((_, i) => new Cell(5, 5));

cells.forEach((cell) => {
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const n = cell.neighbors;
    }
});
```

You can see the results [here](https://jsbench.me/wrkydwks5r/1).  The first method is nearly 65% *slower* than the second method.

Why?  What is happening here?  In both cases, the double loop and "heavy work" is only performed once.  The first case simply returns the class _property as a precomputed value from the get method, and the second case simply returns it as a class property. What is going on that assigning the property in the constructor has better performance than using the accessor method?

Comment: As near as I can tell, it's because you're doing `const n = cell.neighbors;` but have named the property of the class `_neighbors`. Apparently fetching non-existent properties is expensive. Fixing this speeds it up about 10x.

Comment: Changing the benchmark to `const n = cell.getNeighbors()` should make quite a lot of difference: at the moment it's not generating neighbors using the accessor method.  I would also suggest looking at how the neighboring cells are being used - there seem to be too many neighbors being generated to all fit in the same parent matrix.

Comment: "*The `makeNeighbors` boolean is to make sure that every subsequent created `Cell` doesn't try to calculate its neighbors and put us in an inifite loop*" - notice that this approach won't really work, as those cells will not have any neighbors at all, and no way to create them in the future.

Comment: Accessing `const n = cell.neighbors;` is a no-op if the property already exists and is not an accessor. I guess the compiler optimises away the entire inner loop in the second case, [don't trust meaningless microbenchmarks](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html)!

Comment: [Here](https://jsbench.me/ztkye0e2ul/2) is a slightly improved benchmark

Comment: @Bergi thanks for putting the time into those new benchmarks!  The constructor method is *still* the fastest, though your method with `??=` is only 8% slower.  `CellC` seems to simply call `createNeighbors()` every time, because no value is ever assigned to`this._neighbors`  - am I reading that right?  (As far as your comment that neighbor cells will have no way to access their *own* neighbor cells, that's fine.  In my real code, there's actually a `NeighborCell` class, and they don't ever need access to their own neighbors.  This question was more about JS performance)

Comment: @Ouroborus, would you mind elaborating?  Why is fetching non-existent properties expensive?  Does declaring `this._neighbors = null` first solve that problem?

Comment: @SethLutske `??=` is a [nullish assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) and will overwrite the property if it's missing, not the `??` nullish coalescing operator. Basically working the same as the `if` statement in `CellA`, but possibly better (only accessing the property once) or worse (because it's new and might not yet be well-optimised)

Comment: @Bergi I was wondering what the heck that was.  At this level of granularity I swear none of it makes sense.  Like why would that be such a big performance improvement over manually writing `if (this._neighbors) return this._neighbors`?  Or why would be at all faster than a non-accessor method like `this.getNeighbors()`?  Perhaps that article you linked, as confusing as I found it, has some validity.  I think in all cases, declaring in the constructor is the fastest.  But my question is still ***why***?  What's going on under the hood?

Comment: Well the benchmark is heavily geared towards access of the property. The indirection over the getter or get method, the double access of `this._neighbors`, the very `if` condition evaluation counts. Not doing the check is a lot faster. (Of course, if you didn't access the property at all, setting it up unnecessarily in the constructor already would be magnitudes slower).

Comment: @Bergi now you're getting to the crux of the matter.  I know that setting up the property in the constructor will be a waste, if I never access it.  I need to evaluate in my code if every instance of a `Cell` actually uses `.neighbors`, or if it only gets used sometimes.  If its rarely used, the 8% hit in performance that `CellC` creates is totally worth it.  If its used every single time over a large number of `Cells`, maybe its not.  Can you write an answer elaborating on this last comment?  I.e. double access of a property, if evaluation, any other minute operations that affect performance?

Comment: @SethLutske "*I need to evaluate in my code*" - yes, you need to [benchmark **your** code](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)! There is no general recipe (other than to write idiomatic code, which is what engines optimise well). 8% might sound much, but you need to measure your *whole* application. Probably it's premature optimisation, since your code won't access the neighbors billions of times.

Comment: @Bergi lol you linked that article in my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70543701/whats-the-cheapest-method-to-find-all-items-in-a-javascript-map-not-present-in), its a good read.  I am currently coming up with methods to benchmark the whole application on a macro scale (I even wrote [an article](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-automate-performance-profiling-in-nodejs-57524b8f763f) about it on medium).  But less-than-desirable performance on a macro scale has led me to find the small micro places when I can squeeze out better performance, hence this (and the other) question